# Layered Navigation field is not enabled in Magento for attribute

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I want certain attributes to be shown in "shop by" Block, but the problem is "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation" and "Use in Layered Navigation" fields are disabled. Could anyone help me figuring out what is the problem. I checked under `System->Configuration->Catalog->Layered Navigation` there is no problem. The category is set to anchor which is not the problem here. I have reindexed as well, still facing the problem.

Thank you in advance, im using Magento community edition version 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Which attributes are you trying to set as "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation" and "Use in Layered Navigation"?

Pay close attention to the note under those options: *Can be used only with catalog input type Dropdown, Multiple Select and Price.*

So check the Attribute Properties box in the Catalog Input Type for Store Owner field - that needs to be dropdown, multiple select or price.

(Also, I hope you don't mind me saying but non-programming questions would be better asked at (the Magento Stackexchange)[https://magento.stackexchange.com/))

Comment: Thank you for making me understand, just after i posted the question i figured it out.